# Accelerators and sendInputEvent

Tags: electron

According to the [Accelerator](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/accelerator.md) documentation, I should be able to send key commands like `Ctrl+A` and `Return`.

Using the following, I can send key commands one at a time:

```
//ch = current key command, like 'a' or 'Backspace'
webView.sendInputEvent({
  type: 'keyDown',
  keyCode: ch
});

webView.sendInputEvent({
  type: 'char',
  keyCode: ch
});

webView.sendInputEvent({
  type: 'keyUp',
  keyCode: ch
});
```

This works fine for ordinary letter keypresses, and even `Backspace`, but the above won't honor modifier combinations like `Ctrl+A`, or even some single modifiers like `Return` or `Enter`.  If I enter text on a textarea and then send `Return`, I would expect a newline to be added to the textarea.

From the Electron documentation (emphasis mine):

> keyCode String (required) - The character that will be sent as the keyboard event. Should only use the **valid key codes in Accelerator**.

It would seem by that documentation, the newline should get added.

Is that expectation correct?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is "Return (or Enter as alias)" in the current documentation.